# How to add div in new tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="left">
    <img class="img" src="stone1.png"/>
</div>
<div class="center">
    <img class="img" src="stone2.png"/>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <img class="img" src="stone3.png"/>
</div>
```

Now, I want to create this tag whit jQuery:

```
<a href="#" data-r="start" data-a="fade"></a>
```

and put each of div in tag a to create this code:

```
<a href="#" data-r="start1" data-a="fade">
    <div class="left">
        <img class="img" src="stone1.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#" data-r="start2" data-a="fade">
    <div class="center">
        <img class="img" src="stone2.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#" data-r="start3" data-a="fade">
    <div class="right">
        <img class="img" src="stone3.png"/>
    </div>
</a>
```

How do it?

Comment: Use wrapAll... http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Comment: See answers with wrapAll...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('.left, .center, .right').wrap(function(idx){
    return '<a href="#" data-r="start' + (idx + 1) + '" data-a="fade"></a>'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2zG22/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.wrap` method

```
 $('div').each(function(i) {
      $(this).wrap('<a href="#" data-r="start'+ (i+1) + '" data-a="fade">');
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZbXsS/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.img').parent().wrap('<a href="#" data-r="start" data-a="fade"></a>');
```

It selects all the parent elements of element with class `.img` and [wraps](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the element in the specified markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var i = 1;
$("div").each(function(){
var elem = $("<a/>").html(this);

elem.attr("href","#");
elem.attr("data-r","start"+i);
elem.attr("data-a","fade");

i++;console.log(elem);
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/q32Pt/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.left').wrapAll('<a href="#" data-r="start" data-a="fade">');
```